# Optimize Python code for row wise comparison

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have written Python code which uses multiple if condition and a for loop. The main objective of code is to produce traffic light system based on certain condition.

```
Red = -1
Yellow = 0
Green = 1
```

It takes 4 months (m0, m1, m2, m3) and dataframe as an input and run the condition through each rows and return -1, 0 and 1

[image]

The code compares Month 1 with Month 0, Month 2 with Month 1 and Month 3 with Month 2.

For input:

```
if month+1 < Month for any value, then red else green.
```

for example if revenue of July2020 is less than June2020 then input is red else green. Based on three comparison outcome is calculated. Outcome could be either 1-, 0, and 1.

The code I have written works well but not optimised in any way. Is there a better way to do this?

This would be an O(n) operation but, at least there should be a way to write it concisely in python. Or if code can be improved operationally as well.

```
def getTrafficLightData(df, dimension, m1, m2, m3, m4):
'''
Inputs - 
    Dataframe
    dimension = on which we want to calculate traffic light system
    m1, m2, m3, m4 - Could be any for months but we have taken consecutive months for Traffic Light System.
    Example Call - getTrafficLightData(report6_TLS_data, "Revenue_","2020-6","2020-7","2020-8","2020-9")

'''

TFS_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[dimension + "_TLS"])

if dimension == "Overstrike_":
    suffix = "%"
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [-1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [-1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [-1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [0]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (  #
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (  #
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [0]
        else:
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [0]
    return TFS_df
else:
    if dimension == "Margin_":
        suffix = "%"
    else:
        suffix = ""
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [-1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [0]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [-1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [-1]
        elif (
            (
                df[dimension + m1 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m2 + suffix].iloc[i]
                < df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
            and (
                df[dimension + m3 + suffix].iloc[i]
                > df[dimension + m4 + suffix].iloc[i]
            )
        ):
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [0]
        else:
            TFS_df.loc[i] = [0]
    return TFS_df
```

The function is called in below way -

```
report6_TLS_data['Revenue_TLS']=getTrafficLightData(report6_TLS_data, "Revenue_","2020-6","2020-7","2020-8","2020-9")
report6_TLS_data["Margin_TLS"]=getTrafficLightData(report6_TLS_data, "Margin_","2020-6","2020-7","2020-8","2020-9")
report6_TLS_data["Overstrike_TLS"]=getTrafficLightData(report6_TLS_data, "Overstrike_","2020-6","2020-7","2020-8","2020-9")
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

The input data is of form -

```
ym  PART NUMBER BranchCode  Revenue_2019-1  Revenue_2019-10 Revenue_2019-11 Revenue_2019-12 Revenue_2019-2  Revenue_2019-3  Revenue_2019-4  Revenue_2019-5  Revenue_2019-6  Revenue_2019-7  Revenue_2019-8  Revenue_2019-9  Revenue_2020-1  Revenue_2020-2  Revenue_2020-3  Revenue_2020-4  Revenue_2020-5  Revenue_2020-6  Revenue_2020-7  Revenue_2020-8  Revenue_2020-9  Margin_2019-1   Margin_2019-10  Margin_2019-11  Margin_2019-12  Margin_2019-2   Margin_2019-3   Margin_2019-4   Margin_2019-5   Margin_2019-6   Margin_2019-7   Margin_2019-8   Margin_2019-9   Margin_2020-1   Margin_2020-2   Margin_2020-3   Margin_2020-4   Margin_2020-5   Margin_2020-6   Margin_2020-7   Margin_2020-8   Margin_2020-9   Overstrike_2019-1   Overstrike_2019-10  Overstrike_2019-11  Overstrike_2019-12  Overstrike_2019-2   Overstrike_2019-3   Overstrike_2019-4   Overstrike_2019-5   Overstrike_2019-6   Overstrike_2019-7   Overstrike_2019-8   Overstrike_2019-9   Overstrike_2020-1   Overstrike_2020-2   Overstrike_2020-3   Overstrike_2020-4   Overstrike_2020-5   Overstrike_2020-6   Overstrike_2020-7   Overstrike_2020-8   Overstrike_2020-9   Transactions_2019-1 Transactions_2019-10    Transactions_2019-11    Transactions_2019-12    Transactions_2019-2 Transactions_2019-3 Transactions_2019-4 Transactions_2019-5 Transactions_2019-6 Transactions_2019-7 Transactions_2019-8 Transactions_2019-9 Transactions_2020-1 Transactions_2020-2 Transactions_2020-3 Transactions_2020-4 Transactions_2020-5 Transactions_2020-6 Transactions_2020-7 Transactions_2020-8 Transactions_2020-9 Margin_2019-1%  Margin_2019-10% Margin_2019-11% Margin_2019-12% Margin_2019-2%  Margin_2019-3%  Margin_2019-4%  Margin_2019-5%  Margin_2019-6%  Margin_2019-7%  Margin_2019-8%  Margin_2019-9%  Margin_2020-1%  Margin_2020-2%  Margin_2020-3%  Margin_2020-4%  Margin_2020-5%  Margin_2020-6%  Margin_2020-7%  Margin_2020-8%  Margin_2020-9%  Overstrike_2019-1%  Overstrike_2019-10% Overstrike_2019-11% Overstrike_2019-12% Overstrike_2019-2%  Overstrike_2019-3%  Overstrike_2019-4%  Overstrike_2019-5%  Overstrike_2019-6%  Overstrike_2019-7%  Overstrike_2019-8%  Overstrike_2019-9%  Overstrike_2020-1%  Overstrike_2020-2%  Overstrike_2020-3%  Overstrike_2020-4%  Overstrike_2020-5%  Overstrike_2020-6%  Overstrike_2020-7%  Overstrike_2020-8%  Overstrike_2020-9%
0   BAGG001 BC  71.75   90.00   20.25   43.50   42.50   30.00   70.00   44.25   45.00   46.75   129.50  58.00   81.00   36.00   33.25   0.75    15.00   24.75   0.00    0.00    2.50    32.97   39.15   8.95    14.31   18.95   7.86    30.68   19.27   19.74   18.12   59.38   22.30   34.95   17.59   14.10   0.32    6.35    5.30    0.00    0.00    1.06    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    3.00    3.00    1.00    1.00    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    8   16  5   9   5   6   12  7   10  7   13  10  13  5   11  1   2   4   0   0   1   1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    1.00
1   BAGG001 PK  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    25.50   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    9.90    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Comment: Questions to the effect of "Is there a better way to write this?" are better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop you are doing for every row is built in a `pd.DataFrame` with the `apply()` method.

This method basically applies a given function to every row in your `pd.DataFrame`.

Based only in one of your cases, you could do the following:

```
In [0]: import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Month 0":[3,6,3,14,6,3,1,6],
    "Month 1":[1,4,3,15,6,3,4,5],
    "Month 2":[9,4,1,14,1,3,2,1], 
    "Month 3":[1,6,9,14,6,2,6,8],
})

Out[0]:
   Month 0  Month 1  Month 2  Month 3
0        3        1        9        1
1        6        4        4        6
2        3        3        1        9
3       14       15       14       14
4        6        6        1        6
5        3        3        3        2
6        1        4        2        6
7        6        5        1        8
```

Then you can generate your comparison function. It should have 3 possible outcomes,
-1 if the quantity of month 2 is lower than month 1 and so on, 0 if they are similar, and 1 if the quantity of month 2 is greater.

```
def compare(prior, posterior):
    """Compares quantities of two months and it 
    returns -1 if prior is lower, 0 i they are the same,
    and 1 if posterior is greater"""
    
    if posterior < prior:
        return -1
    elif prior == posterior:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Now you can apply this function to your `pd.DataFrame` using apply and the parameter lambda.

```
df["Month_1 Output"] = df.apply(lambda row: compare(row["Month 0"], row["Month 1"]), axis=1)
df["Month_2 Output"] = df.apply(lambda row: compare(row["Month 1"], row["Month 2"]), axis=1)
df["Month_3 Output"] = df.apply(lambda row: compare(row["Month 2"], row["Month 3"]), axis=1)
```

Note that now, you could do a for loop throu the different dimensions you have. Also, if you have several months, is betterto do a for loop than coding everyone separate.
The output from the code above would be:

```
   Month_1 Output  Month_2 Output  Month_3 Output
0               1              -1               1
1               1               0              -1
2               0               1              -1
3              -1               1               0
4               0               1              -1
5               0               0               1
6              -1               1              -1
7               1               1              -1
```

**EDITED**

If you just want to know whether Month + 1 is < month for any value, this would be the same as having just a -1 coming out of the next function so you could do:

```
df["output"] = (
                df[["Month_1 Output","Month_2 Output","Month_3 Output"]].
                    apply(lambda r: (r == -1).any(), axis=1).
                    astype(int)
               )

# With this you would have red as 1 and green as 0, so you could do
df["output"] = df["output"].apply(lambda x: -1 if x==1 else 1)



print(df[["Month_1 Output","Month_2 Output","Month_3 Output", "output"]])

Out[]:
   Month_1 Output  Month_2 Output  Month_3 Output  output
0               0               1               1       1
1              -1               0               1      -1
2               0              -1               1      -1
3               1               1               1       1
4               0              -1               1      -1
5               0               0              -1      -1
6               1               1               1       1
7              -1               1               1      -1
```

Comment: This gives me a data on the left side(input columns), but I need the output columns. For that I have to compare each row and then write 8 conditions. No?

Comment: The same still applies. Anything you want to do in a pandas dataframe that goes like I need to do something in every row, you need to use the apply method. It is best practice and so much clean that for an if loops.

You can check the new edit

Comment: Please if the topic is solved or help vote or close the issue